# Function returns "NoneType" after error check for one input, but not in another

Tags: python, python-3.x

Both functions use the same `check(x)` function and almost identical to each other, except the argument the second function have to take in order to use `print`.

Entering `int` as inputs showed no problem.

However, if alphabets were entered, the return result of `enter_num()` becomes `NoneType`, but this does not happen in `enter_amount()`.

Where and how did it went wrong?

```
def check(x):                           #check if user input is integer
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def enter_num():                        #get user input for lotto numbers
    x = input("buy num:")
    if check(x) == True:                #check int
        x = int(x)
        return x                        
    else:
        print("Please enter integer")
        enter_num()

def enter_amount(x):                    #get user amount of the lottos
    print(x)                          ##if enter_num errored once, this will show None##
    y = input("How many?")
    if check(y) == True:                #check int
        y = int(y)
        print("%s for %s copies" % (x,y))
        return y
    else:
        print("Please enter integer")
        enter_amount(x)                 

buy_num = enter_num()
amount = enter_amount(buy_num)
```

Comment: What is the *full traceback* of the exception you get? Please don't make us guess at this!

Comment: There is no traceback to show because it runs with no error.

Comment: Your use of the term `NoneType` suggests you got an exception *somewhere*, like an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never return the recursive result from `enter_num()`:

```
def enter_num():
    x = input("buy num:")
    if check(x) == True:
        x = int(x)
        return x                        
    else:
        print("Please enter integer")
        enter_num()  # ignoring the return value
    # so None is returned instead
```

The same applies to `enter_amount()`; it *too* ignores the recursive call.

You need to *explicitly return* the recursive call result, just like you would for any other expression:

```
def enter_num():
    x = input("buy num:")
    if check(x) == True:
        x = int(x)
        return x                        
    else:
        print("Please enter integer")
        return enter_num()  # ignoring the return value
```

Do the same for `enter_amount()`; change the last line to `return enter_amount(x)`.

You really should not be using recursion however; all the user has to do is hold the ENTER key for a short amount of time for your code to end up breaking the recursion limit. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for better techniques; a `while` loop would be fine here.

There is also no need to test for `== True`; `if` *already* tests for truth:

```
if check(x):
```

I'd also inline the `check` test; no need to convert to `int()` *twice* if the string can be converted. The following won't run out of recursion depth, but just returns `int(x)` directly if `x` contained a convertible value, or prints an error message otherwise and loops right back to ask for the number again:

```
def enter_num():
    while True:
        x = input("buy num:")
        try:
            return int(x)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter integer")
```

Comment: Thank you. I arbitrarily assumed that if it's just a loopback then the code wouldn't need anything to be returned.

Comment: This is unrelated to the answer. So feel free to vote down, but I do want to express my gratitude. Almost 2 years passed, looking back to this problem reminds me how naive I was. And the fact that you're kind enough to answer this seemingly "idiotic/noobish" question and also kindly teach other related topic helped me up from the ditch and know that there are nice experts, who don't readily spits at latecomers, in this world.

Thank you.